# How can I use IPFS images as twitter card image?

Tags: twitter, meta-tags, ipfs

I want to be able to allow clients to set there own twitter card data with image sourced from there own site or from IPFS.  as a test I made a page with the following meta tags(copied from a market)

```
<meta name="twitter:card" content="summary_large_image" /> 
<meta name="twitter:site" content="https://digiassetX.com/market/#DCbR5qt3BcozuSsu49MeocXvfHkEESf5NL" /> 
<meta name="twitter:title" content="Altar of DigiByte" /> 
<meta name="twitter:description" content="Worlds first MineCraft world DigiAsset.  Take a look around the infinit minecraft world but first hike up to the DigiByte alter where treasures await." /> 
<meta name="twitter:image" content="https://cloudflare-ipfs.com/ipfs/QmXLXP4VBxvAMJtsAhqaPt6koazBpQSzha5EDqpMhdDtKf" />
```

It shows everything except the image correctly.  I suspect the problem is twitter won't get data from cloudflare is there another IPFS gateway they can get it from or some thing I need to change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can switch to one of the public gateways listed [here](https://docs.ipfs.io/concepts/ipfs-gateway/#public-gateways). My personal preferences are `dweb.link` and `storage.link` by [NFT.storage](https://nft.storage).

Comment: dweb.link worked.  NFTstorage did not though.  Thanks.